# ttfamily in the chapter title of Korean language document

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, polyglossia, etoolbox

When having a Korean document and we have `\ttfamily` in a `\chapter` (or other section command) we get an error in respect to etoolbox, and a crash on the line after the `\tableofcontents` (independent of what is after the `\tableofcontents`).

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{korean}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK KR}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans CJK KR}
\newfontfamily\hangulfont{Noto Sans CJK KR}
\newfontfamily\hangulfonttt{Noto Sans CJK KR}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{%
  \fontseries{bc}\selectfont%
}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
Just some text

\chapter{\ttfamily 1}
\end{document}
```

when running xelatex twice over this MWE we get:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Failed to patch part for Korean on input line 22.


! Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'korean@use@script@fonttt' undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.22 J
      ust some text
```

which is in my opinion due to the result of the `\ttfamily` in the in the chapter title.

**Edit**

- Issued issue for polyglossia: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/428
- A fix has been made in the development version of polyglossia: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/428#issuecomment-647139515

Comment: polyglossia redefines \ttfamily so that it is no longer robust and titletoc doesn't like this. Use `\protect\ttfamily`. And open an issue at the polyglossia bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the best way to `\protect \ttfamily`, can I redefine `\ttfamily` in one way or the other in the preamble as the LaTeX code is generated and it is hard to put everywhere `\protect \ttfamily`. I tried `\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\protect \ttfamily}` at the end of the preamble but this didn't work. Will  the `\protect` have any influence on not "section" cvommands? (The section commands are already wrapped like: `\newcommand\doxysection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%{\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`)

Comment: Where the `%` is present and also a `\n` at that place. So when necessary something can be added here (only the `\chapter`  has not yet been wrapped. Though I would prefer  to keep it outside the "section" commands when possible.

Comment: Are there any possibilities with e.g. `\@ifpackagelater{polyglossia}{2020/04/09}{}{...}` as the fix is not released and when released not all users will have the updated package (unfortunately).